# How to cancel GTK3 thread from another thread?

Tags: c, multithreading, gtk, gtk3

I have a graphic application which I am developing using GLib and the `g_thread` functions for creating and manipulating threads. When I press an "ok" button, I create a thread that does some heavy tasks. However I want to have another button named "cancel" that allows me to cancel the created thread at any moment.

I was doing some research but I cannot find any way of doing this: terminating the thread from another place that is not the created thread. The function `g_thread_exit` only can be called from the function that the thread is executing. So my main aim is to cancel the created thread from another thread originated when I click the "cancel" button.

Maybe I have to use the `pthread` library, which has a function called `pthread_cancel` that may fit my expectations.

Thank you so much for any kind of information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can share a `GCancellable` between the two threads, and have the heavy task thread call `g_thread_exit()` when it is cancelled.

Using GLib threads there is indeed no way to directly abort a thread from another thread.